# Can a check with has_key(d, k) and an immediate assignment be short circuited in vim script?

Tags: vimscript

I am wondering if it possible to short circuit the check for the existence of a key in a dict and an immediatly following assignment to a variable with that key if it exists.
That is, if the following code can be abbreviated to something like `let s:val = s:tq84_dict['foo'] || 'default'` (which won't work in vim script)

```
if has_key(s:tq84_dict, 'foo')
  let s:val = s:tq84_dict['foo']
else
  let s:val = 'default'
endif
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`get()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#get%28%29) function:

```
:echo get({}, 'foo', 'default')
default

:echo get({'foo': 'it is set'}, 'foo', 'default')
it is set
```

If you're familiar with Python, this is the same as `{}.get('foo', 'default')`.

Another way would be to use the ternary if:

```
:let dict = {}
:let val = has_key({}, 'foo') ? dict['foo'] : 'default'
:echo val
default

:let dict = {'foo': 'it is set'}
:let val = has_key(dict, 'foo') ? dict['foo'] : 'default'
:echo val
it is set
```

But in this case `get()` is clearly the better way to do it.